# Put the servername, database name and schema automatically before the tablename in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is responsible to import data from database A to database B. I have customers, they all have their own database B (with the same tables etc.) They also have their own database A. The stored procedure will be executed (deployed) on database B.

**The problem:**
 Each customer have another database name for A and B. I found also that database A can be on a different server/instance. I need a generic way to put automatically the server/instance name and the database name from A in my stored procedure to select data from there. Every customer has a connectstring to database A which is already exists in database B. So from the connecstring, I can get the server/instance name and the databasename of A. (I already created a linked server)

**1. What is the best way to put the server/instance name and the database name before the table name??**

**Stored procedure**
 In my stored procedure I have used a lot of variable (declare) tables to insert the data from database A. There are many articles about using dynamic sql but, I cant find an example with a declare table.

**My solution**
 I am thinking about inserting all the data from database A to variable tables. I am importing data from 7 tables, so I need to declare 7 tables and further in my SP I can select data from my declare tables. Note that the hole stored procedure is very huge.

**Questions**
 2.What do you think about my solution?

3.Do you have another solution?

4.How can I insert into my declare table using dynamic sql?

**note that I am using sql server 2005.

```
 I have a few statements like below:

 declare @Temp table (Id int, etc
 insert into @Temp (Id, etc)
 Select Id, etc
 From [databasename].dbo.TableName   //hardcoded
 Where .......

 // doing staff like selecting from the @Temp table etc.


I also have subqueries, but I can change if it is necessary.
```

Comment: Post the code of your current SP here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating #temp, create it as [TempDB].[DBO].[Temp] and it will be accessible outside the dynamic SQL. However, remember to explicitly drop the table, once you are done

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(200)
SET @sql = 'CREATE TABLE tempdb.dbo.temp(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO tempdb.dbo.temp SELECT ''1'' SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.temp'
PRINT (@sql)
EXEC (@sql)
SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.temp

DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.temp
```

Raj

Comment: And do I always have permission to create a table in TempDB?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use dynamic sql to enter into declare tables as the temporary table is only available in the session. Executing any new sql i.e. through dynamic sql will create a new session.

You can get around it by not using any declared or temp tables but instead using a normal table. The dynamic sql will have access to this and anything you do to it isnt lost.

You can prefix your normal tables with something like Temp_ just to note they are temp tables and then make sure you drop them at the beginning of each query i.e.

```
DROP TABLE TEMP_Table
```

You can call multiple local databases by doing

```
SELECT * FROM [DatabaseName].dbo.[TableName]
```

Comment: How can I insert data to the temp_table using dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Check this for creating temporary table in dynamic query

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(200)
SET @sql = 'CREATE TABLE #temp(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT ''1'' SELECT * FROM #temp'
PRINT (@sql)
EXEC (@sql)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8223)

to be precise

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000)
SET @sql = 
    'DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
                Id INT,
                etc
                INSERT INTO @Temp (Id, etc)
                SELECT Id,
                etc
                FROM [databasename].dbo.TableName / / hardcoded
                WHERE ....... SELECT * FROM @temp'

    PRINT (@sql)
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Can I use the temp table outside of the dynamic sql? Like selecting the data in another normal select statement from the just created temp table?

Comment: The problem is when i want to select from the just created temp table, i can not select.

Comment: @Raj: I guess you are creating table on TempDB as you do in normal DB

Comment: I mean, can I make a inner join with the temp that I just created. But in another statement?  After the Exe (@sql) I want start a new query like select ... from Persons inner join @Temp on ...

Comment: @Amedo : surely try it first

Comment: Correct. That is what makes it available outside the session created by the dynamic SQL. Creating it in TempDB would be a better idea than doing it on the production DB. Check my reply to Amedo.

Comment: @brykneval: I tried in your example of SQLFiddle but it is not working. It is outside the session according to Raj

Comment: Its not ouside session, basically dynamic sql builds your query.

Comment: @Amedo, check my answer. That approach will work and will retain the table till you explicitly drop it. It will be accessible outside the session as well

Comment: @Raj: Can I use the production database also? and why a TempDB? Need I create the TempDB?

Comment: TempDB is a system database that already exists. It is where your #temp or @temp gets created. The application may or may not have permissions to create tables in the production DB. Also, creating tables in the production DB is not a good idea

Comment: And do I always have permission to create a table in TempDB? Because I don't know how the customers have the permissions.